# How to get rid of last comma when generating a list?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm writing a web service in ColdFusion.  The problem is that I cannot figure out how to get rid of the comma after the last element. My code looks like this:

```
<cfoutput query="Attachments">
    #url#,
</cfoutput>
```

Which produces output like this (notice the trailing comma)

```
url1,url2,url3,
```

How can I get rid of the trailing comma and produce this instead?

```
url1,url2,url3
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an easy method:

```
<cfoutput>#ValueList(Attachments.url)#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Darn, I am too wordy. You beat me by seconds ;)

Comment: ValueList is the best way in this scenario, but in other cases you could implement a counter and stop when the counter is equal to the record count. something like
`<cfset counter = 1>`
`<cfoutput query="attachments">`
`#url#<cfif counter LT attachments.recordcount>,</cfif>`
`<cfset counter++>`
`</cfoutput>`
ValueList does accept a wide range of delimiters as well

Comment: @mrbusche you don't actually need to set a counter - `currentRow` is available within the loop, so you could just check it this way: `<cfoutput query="attachments"> #url#<cfif attachments.currentRow LT attachments.recordcount>,</cfif></cfoutput>`

Comment: @JakeFeasel Yes, you're correct. I usually end up looping over lists and not queries, so I forget about currerentrow when I'm looping over queries

Comment: I prefer listAppend when you need to conditionally include/exclude elements, then output it: `<cfset clientList=''><cfloop query='clients'><cfif clients.isActive><cfset clientList=listAppend(clientList,clientId)></cfif></cfloop><cfoutput>#clientList#</cfoutput>`

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I found the second to last as the best solution for me and easy to understand, plus it works!

Answer (score 0):

[Jake's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9221558/21960) is what's needed in this particular case.

For more generic cases, you can do this:

```
<cfloop ...>
  <cfset myList=listAppend(myList,value)>
</cfloop>
```

There's also a bit of trickery you can do since ColdFusion (by default) ignores empty list elements:

```
<cfset myList=arrayToList(listToArray(myList))>
```

Heck, even this'll work:

```
<cfset myList=listChangeDelims(myList , "," , ",")>
```

Of course, if you're not outputting the list as a string, you don't need to worry about that comma on the end since ColdFusion will just ignore the empty element. If you are outputting it as a string, here's yet another way to clean up that comma. It's not as reliable as the others, though.

```
<cfoutput>#left(trim(mylist),len(trim(mylist))-1)#</cfoutput>
```